# JavaScript password and page variation

Tags: javascript, passwords, login-script

I am using this code for easy password protection of web pages but I want to edit the code so I can have two different passwords opening two different web pages. So when I enter "Password No.1" it will open "Page No.1" but if I type "Password No.2" it will open "Page No.2".

```
<script>

function TheLogin() {

var password = 'password1';

if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="pageno1.php";
}
else {
  window.alert("Incorrect password, please try again.");
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed in a browser. Anyone browsing to that page can see this code, so they will know your password and the pages it's meant to protect. You cannot secure your pages with JavaScript alone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>

function TheLogin() {

if (this.document.login.pass.value == 'password1') {
  top.location.href="pageno1.php";
}
else if (this.document.login.pass.value == 'password2') {
  top.location.href="pageno2.php";
}
else {
  window.alert("Incorrect password, please try again.");
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the question has already been answered to give you an example of how to accomplish this, its important to note that password protection using javascript is very insecure. The passwords are published plain text in your source and are downloaded onto every user's computer. For any real world protection, this is not acceptable, but perhaps this is ok in your particular use case. Either way, you should at least be aware of it.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that it s not secure but it's enough in this case. Thank you.